# How to put more than one subclass in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can I do something like this ?

```
@interface SomeClass:NSViewController **:NSTableViewController** @end
```

How can i put two subclases in my class ??

Comment: @Justin has the correct answer generally but in your specific case, won't your NSTableViewController already be a subclass of NSViewController so you only need to inherit from NSTableViewController?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objective-C does not support Multiple Inheritance.

Typically, you work around this by using protocols when you want to program to an interface.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSViewController < SomeProtocol >
@end
```

Another option is composition:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
@private
  NSViewController * viewController;
  NSTableViewController * tableViewController;
}
@end
```